# SQL help on query

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I want to create a query for the cheapest package for a holiday to Spain, given package ID. I'm just stuck to how to go about it when executing my query. I need help on what to include in the values for the 'package' table and I also need help on how to present the query.

Here is the table:

```
    USE [zachtravelagency]
    CREATE TABLE package (
        [packageID] INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
        [hotelID] INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES hotels NOT NULL, 
        [excursionID] INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES excursions NOT NULL, 
        [transportID] INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES transport NOT NULL, 
        [flightID] INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES flight NOT NULL, 

    );
```

Here are the columns, followed by some NULL values as I'm not sure what to put in.

```
    Insert Into package (packageID, hotelID, excursionID, transportID, flightID)
    Values (1, '', '', '', '')
```

Here is an example of entering data into my 'hotel' table (this is an example of one row)

```
    Insert Into hotels (hotelID, hotelName, numRooms, location, totalCost, rating)
    Values (1, 'Supreme Oyster Resort & Spa', '255', 'Spain', '250', '4')
```

I'm new to SQL so thank you for your patience.

Comment: No it's part of my module for university I'm really stuck how to go about it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, for your insert statement for 'package', you don't specify packageId since it's an identity column.  Instead it should look something like this

```
Insert Into package (hotelID, excursionID, transportID, flightID)
Values (1, 54, 43, 23)
```

Then to run a SELECT Query to find the cheapest package to Spain you will have to join your hotel, excursion, transport, and flight table on package, and sum the totalCost from each of the tables.

Example:

```
SELECT p.*, (h.totalCost + e.totalCost + t.totalCost, f.totalCost) as 'Total Package Cost' FROM Package p
    INNER JOIN hotel h ON h.hotelId = p.hotelId
    INNER JOIN excursion e ON e.excursionId = p.excursionId
    INNER JOIN transport t ON t.transportId = p.transportId
    INNER JOIN flight f ON f.flightId = p.flightId
WHERE h.location = 'Spain'
ORDER BY (h.totalCost + e.totalCost + t.totalCost, f.totalCost) ASC
```

Your cheapest packages will be listed first.  If you only want the cheapest then you can use SELECT TOP 1

This query also assumes that each of the tables had a totalCost column.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you need to create a total of five tables. Because of the foreign keys you'll have to insert data in the packages table last. Let's assume all that is completed and you now want to query.

If you're given the packageID then you already have the answer. I'm not sure what you mean by that. If you want the minimum cost of a package that has a hotel in Spain then do this:

```
select min(h.totalCost)
from package as p inner join hotels as h on h.hotelID = p.hotelID
where h.location = 'Spain'
```

If you want packages that include a hotel in Spain of the lowest cost, try this. It could match more than one:

```
select * from package where hotelID in (
    select hotelID from hotels where totalCost = (
        select min(h.totalCost)
        from package as p inner join hotels as h on h.hotelID = p.hotelID
        where where p.packageID = ? and h.location = 'Spain'
    )
)
```

Comment: Okay mate, brilliant. How would I go about a package that has the lowest values in all columns of the Package table. For example, hotel, excursions, transport and flight?

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to help you out with what data you should enter in Package table. It can be anything. As long as, data is of the same type as of the type you have provided for each column. Since, all the columns in Package table are integers, you can add any number. Don't put them in '' though. It makes them string. E.g. I'll write following to insert data into Package table:

```
Insert Into package (packageID, hotelID, excursionID, transportID, flightID)
Values (1, 777, 7777, 4444) -- Doesn't matter what value you put, unless you have other Hotel, Excursion, Transport and Flight table which contains Id as primary key, then you need to use that.
```

Similarly, you can insert more records into both tables. After that, use the query provided by user below shawnt00 and it should return you some result.